# What's Laravel's Eloquent search on relation lightest query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

In a classic Rest API approach, my application needs to check if the user is related to a certain account. We can have actions on multiple accounts, so the query is executed on every request.
Since this is our most often called query, it's lightness is important for my peace of mind.

Current query, using Eloquent

```
$user-> accounts()-> where($primaryKey, $id);
```

Somehow, these both generate errors (Eloquent bug?)

```
$user-> accounts()-> find ($id);
$user-> accounts()-> where ($primaryKey, $id)->count();
```

The error:
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'a_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from 'accounts' inner join 'users_accounts' on 'accounts'.'a_id' = 'users_accounts'.'a_id' where 'users_accounts'.'u_id' = 1 and 'a_id' = 1 limit 1)`

Back to my question, is there a more elegant solution then the "where" function?

Answer (score 0):

If this is one of your most used queries, why not cache it?

```
$user->accounts()->where($primaryKey, '=', $id)->remember(60)->get();
```

The mentioned queries fail because you have a column with the same name in both tables

```
where 'users_accounts'.'u_id' = 1 and 'a_id' = 1
```

Comment: Caching is indeed the next step, cheers for reminding. About the query, that one is generated by Eloquent, I do know where it fails, I do however question why Eloquent does generate a failing query. I have to correct you on your last remark, though; where(column, value) is allowed: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I always used the explicit declaration of this param, as it looks more legible to me.

Comment: Would you mind terribly updating the syntax part of your answer? Just to not confuse other readers.